# New line in Label ,CSS Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, css, geoserver-css-module

How do i get a new line in a Geoserver style CSS ?

```
{
label: [name] (need new line here) [pop];
}
```

Details: [name],[pop] are attributes of the layer

Is there a comprehensive CSS documentation with examples for Geoserver? I want the label to look like this [image]

Answer (score 4):

I've never tried it in CSS but in SLD you would use a CDATA block containing the new line:

```
    <ogc:PropertyName>Name_1</ogc:PropertyName><![CDATA[
]]><ogc:PropertyName>Name_2</ogc:PropertyName>
```

so you could try:

```
* {
  stroke-width: 0.2;
  label: [STATE_ABBR]<![CDATA[
]]>[OTHER_VAL];
  label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-fill: black;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 14;
}
```

There is a lot of [CSS documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/index.html) in the GeoServer manual including the [Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/cookbook/index.html), and a [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html) and even a [full workshop](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/workshop/index.html).

**UPDATE**

It turns out that it is easier than I thought you just need to quote the return:

```
* {
  fill: lightgrey;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  label: [STATE_NAME]'
    '[STATE_ABBR];
  label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-fill: black;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 14;
}
```

which gives this image:

[image]

Comment: I tried the label: [STATE_ABBR]<![CDATA[
]]>[OTHER_VAL]; it did not work; instead its throwing an exception asking to write a CQL expression in between < >. I have gone through the documentation but did not find anything related to new line in the label. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: I guess the "indentation" you added is also getting into the map :-)

Comment: probably - I didn't notice that

Comment: @iant you are very close to the answer, where you delete the indentation and the New line is applied with no indentation in the second line. Now the next question is how to control the spacing between the two lines?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it worked like this for my CSS style:

```
* {
 label: [PART1][PART2];
 -gt-label-auto-wrap: 1;
}
```

For me it worked with '1', maybe you need to adapt this value.

If you want it to work in your SLD style I think you need to really add the return between the square brackets in your document. So write:

```
<Label>
<ogc:PropertyName font-family='normal'>PART1</ogc:PropertyName><![CDATA[
]]>
<ogc:PropertyName>PART2</ogc:PropertyName>
</Label>
```

instead of:

```
<Label>
<ogc:PropertyName font-family='normal'>PART1</ogc:PropertyName><![CDATA[]]>
<ogc:PropertyName>PART2</ogc:PropertyName>
</Label>
```

Comment: {
 label: [PART1][PART2];
 -gt-label-auto-wrap: 1;
} this is good suggestion but, if there are two words in the first attribute the auto-wrap wraps the contents of the [PART1] that too.

Comment: Have a look at this post on how to split labels: 
[Split label style in GeoServer CSS or SLD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256045/split-label-style-in-geoserver-css-or-sld)

@iant and Andrea Aime suggested a solution by using offset/displacement that should work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, I have found it useful. Adding to the answer by @Ian Turton:

Although I'm sure there should be a more elegant way, a small hack I apply to fix indentations and spacing is to add a new line at the beginning of the label as well (Yes, you end up with an extra line you have to deal with in label placement):

```
*{
  
    label:
      
"
"
[label_1]
"
"
[label_2];
  
    font-fill:  black;
    font-size: 10;
  
  
}
```